# Xcode Swift Collection View: How can I add the number of items in section whenever the button is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I want to add 1 to the number of items in section whenever the user taps the button, but I have no idea how I should write it in code.

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let numberOfItemsInSection + 1 //What's the correct way to write this line of code?
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return 0 // +1 whenever the button gets tapped
}
```

Comment: use a variable and return it on `numberOfItemsInSection` function...when want to add then just +1 it and reload the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typical to have an array when using `UITableView` & `UICollectionView`.  And the array to be filled with objects.  In your case, the objects would be of type `Item`.

```
var items = [Item]()

@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
    items.append(Item())
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
```

Comment: No problem! @Felix'sHotDogBoss

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
var numberOfItemsInSection = 0

@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any) {
    numberOfItemsInSection += 1 
    yourcollectionview.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfItemsInSection
}
```